# Close a ionic modal in a service

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm working with Ionic 3 (Angular 4) and I would like to close a ionic modal in a service, it's possible ?

[Screen of DataService.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36Bo2.jpg)

I would like call a close() function in another function of my DataService.ts to close my modal deleteconfirm.ts

Comment: I would say not to put view code in a service, you're just asking for headaches.  Instead have the service return a promise and call close from within the promise.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of your code, seems to me like your service will have to know about the view.

What you can do is add an instance of the modal to your service whenever the modal is opened, so that you can refer to that instance to be able to close it as well in the service.

Example (just a made up example as the code in your example is too brief):

```
// Example component
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    modal: Modal;

    constructor(private modalService: ModalService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.modalService.modal = this.modal;
    }

    close() {
        this.modalService.close();
    }
}

// Example service
export class ModalService {
    _modal: Modal;

    set modal(modal: Modal) {
        this._modal = modal;
    }

    close() {
        if (this._modal) {
            this._modal.close();
            this._modal = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This approach allows portability, in that you can close the modal from any component you wish by just injecting the `ModalService`.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I have succeeded thanks to this code in my HTML : (click)="dataService.deleteItem(cle);close()", it's amazing, I did not know it was possible ^^

Comment: No problem!! Yeah, Angular allows you to be as expressive as you'd like in most cases -- which can be both good and bad, I suppose.